# Is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[X]}{(x^2 + x + 2)}$ a field? What is the cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[X]}{(x^2 + x + 2)}$ a field? What is the cardinality?

I know that the polynomial is irreducible, so that quotient is actually a field. The ring has characteristic 3, so is the cardinality of the field just $3^{2}$?

Comment: You mean $\Bbb Z_3[X]$, presumeably. To address your question, why don't you list the elements?

Comment: Yes, I mean $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$, going to edit.

Comment: If $K$ is a field and $f(x)\in K[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ then $L=K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is an extension field of $K$ such that $[L:K]=d$. A $d$-dimensional vector space over a field with $q$ elements has ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has just $3^2$ elements. In fact, every equivalence class has one and only one element of the form $ax+b$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3$. Since there are $3$ choiced for $a$ and $3$ choices for $b$, there are $3^2$ elements.

Comment: I try to formulate the question in a different way, because maybe I do not understand your answer. Is it always true that the cardinality of fields built like the one in my example have cardinality = $(\text{characteristic of field})^{\text{degree of polynomial}}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The argument that I used applies to the general case.

Comment: The argument comes from the division algorithm for polynomials over a field.  Every coset can be represented by a remainder after long division.